# write many arrays to one file -- seperate them with column - "@?" as output

Tags: c, file

I want to write many arrays to one file.

I am using :

```
double *x = (double*) malloc ( ArraySize * sizeof(double) ); 
double *y = (double*) malloc ( ArraySize * sizeof(double) ); 
double *z = (double*) malloc ( ArraySize * sizeof(double) ); 

FILE * theFile;
int N = 3;
double *theFileName[ ] = 
{

[ 0 ] = x ,
[ 1 ] = y , 
[ 2 ] = z

};

theFile = fopen( "mydata", "wb" );
assert( NULL != theFile );

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    fwrite( &theFileName[ i ] , sizeof( double ) , ArraySize , theFile + i );

fclose( theFile );
```

My questions/problems:

1) Using

> theFile + i

results in seg fault.

How can I ensure that each array will be written to different portion of theFile then?

2) Is there a way to write every array in different column in order to be able to process the data?

------UPDATE--------------

I found that for creating "columns" ,I can do :

```
fwrite( x + i , sizeof( double ) , ArraySize  , theFile );
fwrite( "\t" , sizeof( char ) , 1  , theFile );
fwrite( y + i , sizeof( double ) , ArraySize  , theFile );
fwrite( "\n" , sizeof( char ) , 1  , theFile );
```

but even if I use "mydata.txt" I am getting "@?" as output.

Ok , fwrite is for binary format only but is there a way to just check the numbers?

I am confused with fortrans "write" to dat file where you can see the numbers.

Comment: What do you think `theFile + i` is supposed to do?

Comment: @Arkadiy:It supposes to save each array to the next file position,but it is not needed according to the John Zwinck answer.

Comment: @George, please consider `theFile + i` from the C language syntax and semantics point of view. Also, define "next file position". Next byte? next record? next line? In many of these case, you have to ask youself questions and try to answer them from teh compiler's point of view.

Comment: @Arkadiy:yes , you are right.I had to step i equals the number of elements of each array.I mixed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is simple formatted output to a text file -- so you can open and read it. If that is the case, `fprintf` is what you want, not `fwrite`:

```
theFile = fopen( "mydata", "a" );

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    fprintf (theFile, "%f\t%f\n", (double)(*(x+i)), (double)(*(y+i)));
```

Comment: Using `"%.2f"` to write numbers like `1e100` would produce a corresponding 103 some digit output of which only the first 20 or so are meaningful.  Any |number| less than `0.005` would print as `0.00` losing all significant digits.  Better to use `"%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, (double)(x+i)`.

Comment: Good catch - fixed - just for the simple case `%f`. Rather than getting into a `what's the best way to format a double` discussion.

Comment: @George, thanks fixed. `x[i] = *(x+i)`. You still need to pass a double to `%f` so it should be `(double)(*(x+i))`. Give it a shot. I didn't compile/test the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite` automatically advances the file pointer.  You just pass `theFile` to it each time, without adding anything, and it will keep adding to the output file.

Comment: :Ok , thanks.What about the column thing?I tried to save to dat file but it doesn't work

Comment: Well your data writing is messed up too, for example what is `sizeof( double )` doing there?  You're writing single-character strings, so it seems you should say `1` as the size.  Or perhaps you meant to be writing arrays of doubles instead of strings, but that's not what your code does.

Comment: :Ok, I updated (I had left it as char sorry).What should I use in order to take dat file?Becuae I am trying  "mydata.dat " , "w" or "wb" , neither works

Comment: "The file pointer" is a really scary way to put it, since the code uses a `FILE *` that certainly is not incremented. What is incremented is the *position* inside the file.

Answer (score 2):

A file in C is just a stream of bytes. `fwrite` just means write next N bytes, while fread means "read next N bytes".

There is no such thing as "column" in C file. Any structure you need in the file, you need to impose yourself.

Comment: :And how can we use something like fwrite( x + "\t" , sizeof( double ) , ArraySize , theFile ); ?? (add "\t")

Comment: Why do you insist on using `sizeof(double)`? How is it relevant? What is the type of `x`? What do you expect `x+"\t"` to produce? May be you should look into line-oriented file APIs, such as fprintf, fscanf, fgets, fputs.

Comment: :x is double ,please check code. I am just using an example when using x+ "\t".I mean , can I use sth in order to leave a tab space between writes?

Comment: You can't add double and string - this is not Java

Comment: :I am not saying that I can...Just the idea